# Templated class member VS Nested class forward declaration

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Good evening everyone!

I'm stuck with an itchy problem. Say I have the following code :

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct MyTemplate {
    int _array[sizeof (T)];
} ;

struct MyStruct {

    struct MyNestedStruct {
        int foo;
    } ;

    MyTemplate<MyNestedStruct> _nested;
} ;

int main(int, char **) {
    return 0;
}
```

This example snippet compiles fine. What I would like to do is lift the definition of MyNestedStruct out of MyStruct :

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct MyTemplate {
    int _array[sizeof (T)];
} ;

struct MyStruct {
    struct MyNestedStruct;

    MyTemplate<MyNestedStruct> _nested;
} ;

struct MyStruct::MyNestedStruct {
    int foo;
} ;

int main(int, char **) {
    return 0;
}
```

Of course this one doesn't compile since I'm requesting the size of a partially declared type (**error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘MyStruct::MyNestedStruct’**).

My real use case does need sizeof, but will also use *several* MyNestedClass-like template parameters in that fashion, each fully declared with constructors and the like. For this reason  I don't want MyClass to get bloated. Can I do anything about it, or will I have to resort to an external scope (namespace) to put my "inner" classes in ?

Unless...

```
struct MyStruct {
#include "MyNestedStruct.h" // Dirty preprocessor to the rescue !
    MyTemplate<MyNestedStruct> _nested;
} ;
```

Ugh.

Comment: IF you're pulling `MyNestedStruct` out, why does it still need to be scoped inside of `MyStruct` ? Why not just make it a totally separate class. That should solve the issue.

Comment: Semantics. Using simple separate classes would of course do the trick, but all those nested classes are semantically siblings, and subcomponents of MyClass. So having them inside Myclass' scope would be the most adequate way of naming them. I'm probably a bit OCD on this one though :)

Comment: Having a child class would be a good idea in case you needed something from the outer scope, e.g. template parameters of parent class. You are using child classes in a wrong way. Though I've tried several ways to fix the problem, none of which helped. It would be pretty interesting to see a solution just in case it happens to me.

Comment: Hmm. I first discovered nested classes with Java, where they very much carry this notion of "sub-objects". What exactly would they represent in C++ then ? (if this can be answered concisely enough not to demand its own SO question)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Java, but it looks like C++'s nested classes are much like Java's *static* nested classes. -- You can also use a namespace to group related things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially we need to defer template instantiation of `MyTemplate` since that's the one that requires `T` to be complete. The trick I can see to do that here is to templatize `MyStruct`.

```
 template <typename T>
 struct MyTemplate {
   int _array[sizeof(T)];
 };

 template <typename Dummy = void>
 struct MyStruct {
   struct MyNestedStruct;

   MyTemplate<MyNestedStruct> _nested;
 };

 template <typename Dummy>
 struct MyStruct<Dummy>::MyNestedStruct {
   int foo;
 };

 int main() {}
```

Now we've deferred the instantiation of `MyStruct`, but we need to use `MyStruct<>` instead. If that's unsatisfactory, then just provide a type alias.

```
 #include <iostream>

 template <typename T>
 struct MyTemplate {
   int _array[sizeof(T)];
 };

 template <typename Dummy = void>
 struct MyStructImpl {
   struct MyNestedStruct;

   MyTemplate<MyNestedStruct> _nested;
 };

 template <typename Dummy>
 struct MyStructImpl<Dummy>::MyNestedStruct {
   int foo;
 };

 using MyStruct = MyStructImpl<>;

 int main() {
   MyStruct s;
   std::cout << sizeof(s._nested._array) << std::endl;
 }
```

Prints `16`.

**Note:** you could also to hide `MyStructImpl` in a `detail` namespace or something similar.

Comment: That seems so simple now that I see it... That's what "clever" means, I guess.